# Ruby to Java Crypto Functionality using BouncyCastle

Tags: java, ruby, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am trying to convert some ruby openssl calls to java (using BouncyCastle). however its my first time using BouncyCastle, so I am having some issues with figuring out some of the API usage for my case.

Essentially, I am trying to convert Apples MDM Enrollment process to Java. Apples sample code is written in Ruby, and it starts off as follows:

```
p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(input)
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
p7sign.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
p7enc = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new(p7sign.data)
out = p7enc.decrypt(key, cert)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't really found the BouncyCastle documentation to be very helpful, so any help in how to convert this to java would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,